# Xcode Project with multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a project directory which has multiple cpp files. Each of these files has a main function tied to the respective files. Can i execute each of these files individually or do i have to modify some configurations in Xcode to target each of the files individually. If so, what are steps that i have to take?

This is what the structure looks like in Xcode

```
Project1
  Project1
    main1.cpp
    main2.cpp
    main3.cpp
```

Comment: you need to have multiple targets where each target only include one of the main files

Comment: @BryanChen how can i do that, i am new to the Xcode environment

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019742/xcode-multiple-projects-more-than-one-main-executable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's relatively straight forward to have multiple targets under the same project:

1. Click on your project in the project navigator:

[image]

2. Go to your target, here;

[image]

3. Go to "add target":

[image]

4. Select "macOS" and scroll down to "command line tool":

[image]

5. Give it a name, and finish:

[image]

6. You'll see both target in the same project:

[image]

7. Next to the 'run' and 'stop' buttons, set your active scheme to the desired main file:

[image]